# Each thread using its own proxy

Tags: java, http, networking, https, proxy

I'm trying to set up a Java program, where each thread can use its own proxy.

Right now I only found a way to set a proxy globally. (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html)

> As mentioned earlier, these settings affect all http connections
>   during the entire lifetime of the VM invoked with these options.
>   However it is possible, using the System.setProperty() method, to have
>   a slightly more dynamic behavior.
>
> Here is a code excerpt showing how this can be done:
>
> //Set the http proxy to webcache.mydomain.com:8080
>
> System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "webcache.mydomain.com");
>   System.setPropery("http.proxyPort", "8080");

## Update

I tried using the proxy class, yet can't create a direct connection for when I don't want to use said proxy:

```
private void setProxy()
{
    if(proxyUrl != null)
    {
        SocketAddress addr = new InetSocketAddress(proxyUrl, proxyPort);
        proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, addr);
    }
    else
    {
        proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.DIRECT, null);
    }       
}
```

`Exception in .... java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: type DIRECT is not compatible with address null`

How can I get this to work for direct connections? Haven't tried proxies yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe use the [Proxy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Proxy.html) class as explained [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html) in section 3:

> As we have seen, the system properties are powerful, but not flexible.
>   The "all or nothing" behavior was justly deemed too severe a
>   limitation by most developers. That's why it was decided to introduce
>   a new, more flexible, API in J2SE 5.0 so that it would be possible to
>   have connection based proxy settings.

You could use [Proxy.NO_PROXY](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Proxy.html#NO_PROXY) to:

> ... not to use any proxying.

Do something like this:

```
private void setProxy()
{
    if(proxyUrl != null)
    {
        SocketAddress addr = new InetSocketAddress(proxyUrl, proxyPort);
        proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, addr);
    }
    else
    {
        proxy = Proxy.NO_PROXY;
    }       
}
```

Comment: Some more hours until I'll be able to try that

Comment: Upvoted your answer, but accepted my own. I still had some problems with your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Barry NL's solution semi-worked, since I couldn't figure out how to not use a proxy with that solution.

What I came up with:

`proxyUrl` and `proxyPort` are in the constructor of my class.

I wasn't able to call `url.openConnection(proxy);` if I just set `proxy = null`

or `proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.DIRECT, null);` .
So I wrote my own `openConnection`

```
private void setProxy()
{
    if(proxyUrl != null)
    {
        SocketAddress addr = new InetSocketAddress(proxyUrl, proxyPort);
        proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, addr);
    }
    else
    {
        proxy = null;
    }       
}
private URLConnection openConnection2(URL url)
{
    try {
        if(proxy != null)               
            return url.openConnection(proxy);               
        else 
            return url.openConnection();            
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }   
}
```

`setProxy()` has to be called before making any connections.

Also I replaced

```
url = new URL(http_url);
con = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection(proxy);
```

with

```
url = new URL(http_url);
con = (HttpURLConnection)openConnection2(url);
```

Comment: I have updated my answer with a solution to your updated question. I think it is the official way of doing it and results in cleaner code (less ifs).

Comment: I tried it with DIRECT, didn't know there was a NO_PROXY . I'll test it later, looks nice tho. I accepted your answer.